# Offset in a Poisson GLM (R)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, r-squared, offset

I am trying to model disease counts (d) by using population (p) as offset to control for exposure. In R, I found two possible ways to go:

```
m1 <- glm(d ~ 1 + offset(log(n)), family=poisson, data=dat)
m2 <- glm(d ~ 1, family=poisson, data=dat, offset=log(n))
```

The summary of my and m2 shows that `summary(m1)` = `summary(m2)` but if I try to calculate the McFadden through the `pR2` (pscl package): `McFadden(m1)` ≠ `McFadden(m2)`.

Does someone have an explanation for that?

Comment: Only you have `dat` -  it'd be useful to illustrate the issue using one of the built-in datasets, as well as providing the rest of the code to calculate McFadden's $R^2$. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: See this post for more information: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022213/pseudo-r%C2%B2-for-a-poisson-glm-with-offset/31022956#31022956][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022213/pseudo-r%C2%B2-for-a-poisson-glm-with-offset/31022956#31022956

Comment: As explained in [help/on-topic], please don't crosspost but pick one best place for your question. It's also no use pointing to another post that makes the same formatting errors in the hope of avoiding having to fix it here. Please fix the same errors in that other post.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the source code of `pscl:::pR2.glm`:

```
function (object, ...) 
{
    llh <- logLik(object)
    objectNull <- update(object, ~1)
    llhNull <- logLik(objectNull)
    n <- dim(object$model)[1]
    pR2Work(llh, llhNull, n)
}
<environment: namespace:pscl>
```

If the offset is specified in the formula, it gets lost in the second line (`update` to compute the intercept-only model).

See this example:

```
library("foreign")
ceb    <- read.dta("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/ceb.dta")
ceb$y  <- round(ceb$mean*ceb$n, 0)
ceb$os <- log(ceb$n)  

m0 <- glm(y ~ res + offset(os), data=ceb, family=poisson)
m1 <- glm(y ~ res, offset=os, data=ceb, family=poisson)

all.equal(coef(m0), coef(m1))
# [1] TRUE

### compute null models
coef(update(m0, ~1))  # wrong, offset not considered
# (Intercept) 
#        5.02 
coef(update(m1, ~1))
# (Intercept) 
#       1.376 
coef(update(m0, ~1, offset=os))
# (Intercept) 
#       1.376
```

Answer (score -3):

I did some tests and the offset seems not to be included in m2. 
The right way to go to include an offset in a glm is:

```
m1 <- glm(d ~ 1 + offset(log(n)), family=poisson, data=dat)
```

The problem seems not to be due to the pscl package but to the formulation of the glm.

Comment: I would say that "the problem" is the mistake you made in writing your R code rather than "the formulation of the glm."

Comment: (-1) The answer by @rcs shows this is the *wrong* way to include an offset if you want `pR2` to take note of it.